# Split an integer interval into bins of almost equal length

Tags: r

Lets say I have `start=1`, `end=12` and the interval `start:end`.

I want to split it in bins of `x=2` so that i will get a data frame of

```
 start.index end.index
1           1         2
2           3         4
3           5         6
4           7         8
5           9        10
6          11        12
```

In this case it results to 6 bins. `start`, `end`, and `x` are always integers

Is there any function to do this? Obvisouly when `start%%x!=0` the one bin might be larger or smaller than the others but I dont mind.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of such a function:

```
foo <- function(start, end, x = 2) {
    SEQ <- seq(start, end, by = x)
    END <- SEQ + (x - 1)
    take <- END > end
    END[take] <- end
    data.frame(start.index = SEQ, end.index = END)
}

R> foo(1, 12, 2)
  start.index end.index
1           1         2
2           3         4
3           5         6
4           7         8
5           9        10
6          11        12
R> foo(1, 12, 3)
  start.index end.index
1           1         3
2           4         6
3           7         9
4          10        12
R> foo(1, 12, 4)
  start.index end.index
1           1         4
2           5         8
3           9        12
```

And with an odd number of observations so we get different bin widths for the last one:

```
R> foo(1, 11)
  start.index end.index
1           1         2
2           3         4
3           5         6
4           7         8
5           9        10
6          11        11
```